# I am writing a script to copy a file Url to an Html Output. The issue I am having is the Url code has the text '?usp=drivesdk' added to the Url

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My code to get the Url (from a new worksheet that has been copied)

```
DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(nom,destFolder).getUrl();

var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d' +  '/" target="_blank">' + fileUrl + '</a>')
    .setWidth(350).setHeight(50);

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput,'Flowcalculator');
```

The Html shows the correct Url for the new file except it has an ending ....../edit?usp=drivesdk.
Do I need to write a 'format' function to delete the ?usp=drivesdk.  or change the suffix to 'share' (I want the user to be able to open the file from the ModalDialog by clicking on the Url

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your situation, even when `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/edit?usp=drivesdk` is used as the hyperlink for opening the Spreadsheet, the link can be used.

I thought that in your script, `'<a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d' +  '/" target="_blank">' + fileUrl + '</a>'` is required to be modified. In this case, the URL is `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/`. This cannot be used.

If you want to open the copied Spreadsheet by clicking the link on the dialog, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var fileUrl = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(nom, destFolder).getUrl();
var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<a href="${fileUrl}" target="_blank">${fileUrl}</a>`).setWidth(350).setHeight(50);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Flowcalculator');
```

- In this case, please declare the variables of `sheet`, `nom`, and `destFolder`.
- If you want to use `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/edit?usp=sharing` instead of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/edit?usp=drivesdk`, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      var fileUrl = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(nom, destFolder).getUrl();
    ```
  - To

    ```
      var fileUrl = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(nom, destFolder).getUrl().replace("drivesdk", "sharing");
    ```

Comment: Excellent - many many thanks.  I am not a script writer and have recently unskilled by learning basic VBA then moving to Google Sheet and have 'discovered' script/java only 4 or 5 weeks ago.  Its been a lot of trial and error, and google learning.  Cheers

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I can't see the checkbox to accept your answer, I run a Mac and am not sure if that is different